# Brightness goes to minimum if I press the brightnrss control button after each boot

Tags: boot, laptop, brightness

After the boot, the brightness is always maximum. Whenever I press brightness control button (function keys), my brightness automatically goes to minimum. Then I have to manually adjust it. It couldn't just retain the same brightness of the previous session each and every time I boot. It is happening only in the versions of Ubuntu 20.04+, before that like in 18.04 or 16.04 everything was perfect.

Comment: Provide information on your computer and graphics cards.

Comment: Laptop model no. Lenovo E41-25, CPU- AMD PRO A6-7350B R5, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G (integrated), 4GB ram

Comment: Use "edit" to add information that is essential to better frame your question to the question itself.